# Htaccess mod rewrite?

Tags: .htaccess, mod_rewrite

1. Есть файл `1.zip` он находится `site.ru/dir1/dir2/1.zip`
     Каким образом можно реализовать чтобы по запросу `site.ru/blabla` выдавался 1.zip
2. И сразу же подобный второй запрос файл лежит `site.ru/5477865/1.zip`
   Мы смотрим в базе есть ли 5477865 если есть то выдаем `1.zip` если нету то редирект к примеру на индекс

Читал про `mod rewrite` с регулярными выражениями дружу плохо.. ничего не понял

Answer (score 1):

Так надо вначале подружится иначе что ты из объяснения поймешь?

[Как на самом деле работает `mod_rewrite`. Пособие для продолжающих](http://habrahabr.ru/company/sprinthost/blog/129560/)